# How to deal with all the Casper questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Casper is yet only and idea and there are not many hard facts available out there.

Still, there are so many questions popping up on that topic, [casper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casper) (15) [proof-of-stake](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-of-stake) (21).

Most of the questions are legit, but there is no way currently for anyone to give accurate answers. How to deal with all the Casper questions?

Comment: I'm a little tempted to call on Vlad Zamfir, who manages Casper. Not sure if he's already a part of this SE or not, but it would be helpful to have him around and provide the highest degree of certainty there is, as a temporary fix, until we have more experts around. Not saying he should be monitoring 24/7 but his presence would help... IMO

Comment: @Joël sounds quite reasonable.

Comment: @eth tweeted him...

Comment: He's joining tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

How much does the statistic of answers-to-questions, number of questions without answers, etc affect this SE Beta?

I agree most of the questions are legit, and reasonable answers to them may only come much later...

If the statistic like a low number of questions without answers is critical for the Beta, maybe we need to add another category/reason to be able to put such questions on hold if that will help the statistics be more accurate?  Since they are tagged with [casper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casper) we'll then be able to re-open them more easily when more information is available?

Then again, the number of unanswerable questions may not affect the statistics in a noticeable way.  So we'll be ok.

(A potential downside is people chiming in with speculative low-quality answers: or simply an accurate but low-quality answer like "it's unknown at the moment".  Well, we can delete those if they happen.

Comment: My concern is not about the statistics, but about the low quality answers based on uncertainty.

Comment: Not to get too meta in the meta section, but this is a direct result of how these concepts are communicated to the 'general public'. I would like all discussion of this stuff tabled until the code is available. I think it's... kinda dishonest to imply that casper is "just around the corner" when there is no code.

Comment: everyone is expending a lot of time and effort and so it is incumbent on someone somewhere to provide answers since if you do not know where you are going any road will do.. albeit this could be a generic 'we know nothing with regard to the Casper final outcome, 'although it may not be as blunt...